# ganache npm start error

Tags: python, node.js, windows, truffle, ganache

When I run 'npm start' in Windows Powershell, I get the error listed below.  'npm install' in the ganache directory succeeded, but I can't determine why ganache won't start.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix or further isolate the problem. I am running Windows 7 with the latest ganache and am running the latest node.js.

PS C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache> npm start

```
> ganache@1.0.2 start C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache
> electron-forge start

npm : âˆš Checking your system
At line:1 char:1
+ npm start
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (âˆš Checking your system:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

âˆš Locating Application
Ã— Preparing native dependencies: 0 / 1
An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 523, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 2019, in GenerateOutput
    sln_projects, project_objects, flat=msvs_version.FlatSolution())
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1778, in _GatherSolutionFolders
    return _DictsToFolders('', root, flat)
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1731, in _DictsToFolders
    for folder, contents in bucket.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'MSVSProject' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\GitHub\\ganache\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.6.11" "--arch=x64" 
"--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=fse" 
"--module_path=C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\GitHub\\ganache\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\electron-v1.6-win32-x64" "--remote_path=./v1.1.3/" 
"--package_name=fse-v1.1.3-electron-v1.6-win32-x64.tar.gz" "--host=https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed with exit code: 1
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 523, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 2019, in GenerateOutput
    sln_projects, project_objects, flat=msvs_version.FlatSolution())
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1778, in _GatherSolutionFolders
    return _DictsToFolders('', root, flat)
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1731, in _DictsToFolders
    for folder, contents in bucket.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'MSVSProject' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\GitHub\\ganache\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.6.11" "--arch=x64" 
"--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=fse" 
"--module_path=C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\GitHub\\ganache\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\electron-v1.6-win32-x64" "--remote_path=./v1.1.3/" 
"--package_name=fse-v1.1.3-electron-v1.6-win32-x64.tar.gz" "--host=https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed with exit code: 1
    at SafeSubscriber._error (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:277:84)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:239:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:198:26)
    at Subscriber._error (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:129:26)
    at Subscriber.error (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:103:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:129:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:103:18)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:251:65)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:248:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:188:27)
    at Subscriber._next (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:126:26)
    at Subscriber.next (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:90:18)
    at DefaultIfEmptySubscriber._next (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\operators\defaultIfEmpty.js:67:26)
    at DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\S
ubscriber.js:90:18)
    at TakeLastSubscriber._complete (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\operators\takeLast.js:102:29)
    at TakeLastSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (C:\Users\username\Documents\GitHub\ganache\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:115:18)
npm

ERR!

code
 ELIFECYCLE
npm

ERR!

errno
 1
```